# Stripe Payment Integration

Tags: stripe-payment-intent

I want to integrate Stripe in such a way that first it validates the card and amount and returns a session or some sort of id. And then once validated using the same session id or payment Id process the payment to the desired account number which will be updated later as the account number here is coming after the validation and this account number is then used in the previously created and validated session/ payment Id. This is some what like setting up a payment intent but processing the actual payment later on when destination account number is available.
Please advise.
Thanks in advance :)

Tried Setup Intent and Payment Intent